# Updating an item in an embedded document in MongoDB using Java MongoClient

Tags: java, mongodb, micronaut

I have a below data in mongo db

```
{
    "_id": "6033c4b184116e3dfdc39d1a",
    "description": "Men description",
    "name": "Men",
    "subCategory": [{
            "_id": "60365216fcc02725299e1eb6",
            "name": "This is something I was looking for",
            "description": "This is the description update"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sub category 2",
            "description": "Sub category description 2",
            "_id": "6036578cf4c19360225ca2f0"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update the `subCategory._id = 6036578cf4c19360225ca2f0` using the java driver for mongoDb as below

```
Bson query = and(
  eq("_id", new ObjectId("6033c4b184116e3dfdc39d1a")),  
  eq("subCategory._id", new ObjectId("6036578cf4c19360225ca2f0"))
);

Document documentList = new Document();
documentList.append(String.format("%s","name"), "name update 1");
documentList.append(String.format("%s","description"), "Description Update 1");
Document document = new Document("$set", new Document("subCategory", List.of(documentList)));

 Single.fromPublisher(
 this.repository.getCollection(
 ConstantValues.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_COLLECTION_NAME, Category.class)
.updateOne(query, document)).subscribe();
```

When I run this code, it adds the completely new item removing all the item. How can I update the particular field.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I found that ***The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array.***

Now the document code will change as below

```
Document documentList = new Document();
documentList.append(String.format("%s.$.%s","subCategory","name"), "name update 1");
documentList.append(String.format("%s.$.%s","subCategory","description"), "Description Update 1");
Document document = new Document("$set",documentList));
```

Reference - https://riptutorial.com/mongodb/example/22368/update-of-embedded-documents-

https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-work-with-embedded-document-in-mongodb-collection-379